# Bad request when trying to retrieve data from server using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm just learning how to use Axios and I'm trying to retrieve the username stored in a jwt from the server. However, I'm getting ERR_BAD_REQUEST and I'm not sure as to why.

Below is the request I make to the server

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/getuserdata', {
       token: localStorage.getItem('token')
    }).then((response) => {
      setUsername("/home/" + response.username)
      console.log(username)
    })
  }, [])
```

This is the how the server handles the request

```
app.post('/api/getuserdata'), async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, '<My Password>')
    const username = decoded.username
    return res.json({username: username})
}
```

From what I can tell this should be setting the username but it's always a bad request. What am I missing?

Comment: You need the scheme in your url

Comment: What's a scheme?

Comment: The http/https part of a url

Comment: That didn't fix my issue